# implementing a Chrome extension on/off toggle button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, event-handling, callback, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to implement an on/off toggle for my extension, which is a content script that hooks into the "beforeload" event and selectively cancels requests based on some logic (eg. you want to prevent a certain domain's URLs from loading, a specific URL from loading, etc.).

I am setting an "enabled" variable in my background page and using `chrome.extension.sendRequest()` in my content script & `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener()` in my background extension page to retrieve the extension's enabled/disabled state

background script:

```
Settings = {};
Settings.enabled = 1;

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

        if (request.getState == "enabled") {
            sendResponse({result: Settings.enabled});
        } else {
            sendResponse({});
        }
    }
);
```

I have a pop-up page that handles setting the enabled/disabled variable. When the "enable" button is clicked, `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().Settings.enabled = 1;` fires, and when the "disable" button is clicked,
`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().Settings.enabled = 0;` fires (this functionality works fine)

My content script **before** I started checking for the "enable/disable" variable  (`should_block_request` is pseudocode):

```
(function() {
    document.addEventListener("beforeload", function(event) {
        if (should_block_request) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, true);
}());
```

And here it is **afterwards**, using message passing with `chrome.extension.sendRequest()` to query the "enabled" setting in the background page, and doing the request blocking logic inside its callback

```
(function() {
    document.addEventListener("beforeload", function(event) {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({getState: "enabled"}, function(response) {
            var enabled = response.result;
            if (!enabled) {
                return; 
            } else {
                if (should_block_request) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            };
        });
    }, true);
}());
```

The "before" content script works as expected, blocking requests when the criteria are met, but when i try the "afterwards" version of my content script, the criteria are **still** met, but the requests are not blocked even though event.preventDefault() is called.

Is chrome.extension.sendRequest() the right way to check for the Settings.enabled variable inside a "beforeload" event handler callback? Does event.preventDefault() need to be called a level higher than I currently have it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but in chrome v16 and later extensions may disable/enable javascript.

Here's one such extension: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71067